# Programmatically delete Messages conversations?

Tags: messages, privacy

I have so many conversations, I want to delete those I haven't used in more than 30 days. Apple does not offer this functionality, so I want to write an app that does it. The App will need to run on the desktop. Is there any way to do this with applescript or an Objective-C or SWIFT API?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but it might be a bit simpler to check if Automator can do that.

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: @Todd - how would I do it with Automator?